# java script to like youtube video

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube

i made a function in java script to like youtube video code is

```
 function LikesDislikes ()
{

$.ajax({

url: 'gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/U5wVEr91Kpw/ratings',
type:"POST",
data: '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"xmlns:yt="http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007"><yt:rating value="like"/></entry>',
```

**headers:**

```
 {

    "Content-Type":"application/atom+xml",

    "Authorization":"Bearer ya29.AHES6ZQru5sIgtlj7a_-C7HkjYQH-9AwYwL8CWay3b2ZiHc",
    "X-GData-Key":"key=AIzaSyAPrtP2Tq4m5WVInCvCWptVAKPhQ4SQNZA",
    "GData-Version":"2"
  }


  });

 }
```

Can any one help me i don't know code is right or not i m getting error 400 not found ,please help me

thanks

Comment: 400 is "bad request", 404 is "not found". Which are you getting?

Comment: i am getting Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)  this error

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to put `http://` on the front of your URL, so you are making the request to your own server.

(But you would probably be best off throwing all this code away and using [the JavaScript library that Google provide](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-javascript-client/).)

Comment: when i use http;// in my url i found this error   Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)

Comment: That's a *different* problem. Your XML is obviously invalid (use a validator) and seems to be missing some vital data (such as *what* you are trying to like). I very strongly recommend not trying to do this by hand and just using the library that Google gives you.

Comment: but how can i  like a youtube video using google api please can u explain bcz i m new .please help me